# Why is my string output printing out weird characters?

Tags: c#, arrays, listview, encoding, utf-8

So I have this method that prints out a few lines from a textfile to a listview but whenever it does it it takes characters such as "Å å , Ä ä, Ö ö" and makes them weird symbols like triangles and stuff.
I tried converting them to UTF-8 Characters but it gave me the same output.

```
private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Convert to utf8

    string[] Accounts = File.ReadAllLines(filePath); // if null do something

    foreach (string account in Accounts)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(account);
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    }

}
```

This is what the textfile list looks like

> Gräsklippare@hotmail.com
>  Åkerström@gmail.com

Yep, thats it.

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines` has an overload that takes an encoding. Call it with whatever encoding was used for that file (apparently not UTF8)

Comment: Found it! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.ReadAllLines` has an overload that takes an encoding. Call it with whatever encoding was used for that file (apparently not UTF8)

Answer (score 0):

As @KevinGosse pointed out, the File.ReadAllLines() has an overload that takes an encoding and the encoding that was needed for this set of characters was UTF-7

Working Code

```
private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Convert to utf8

            string[] Accounts = File.ReadAllLines(filePath, Encoding.UTF7); // if null do something

            foreach (string account in Accounts)
            {
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(account);
                listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
            }

        }
```